# How to read my own rank status in counter strike 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

[image]

On screen there is a rank status displayed. How do I know my own status?

NOTE: Displayed rank is not mine.

Comment: As someone who doesn't play the game, why is it showing the rank of someone else?

Comment: @TimmyJim what? If you are concern regarding the pic then I can see other players rank but I can't see my own rank. Also, I play the game but unfortunately I can't read my own rank. But yes, numerical ranks is available which I can and not the rank status.

Comment: The chance would be that "rank" is some system that's only able to see in some specific community servers that has some kind of mod(s), since by googling "Counter strike 1.6 United forces member" isn't giving anything of the sort. Plus, I've played CS 1.6 for like 3k hours, but I've never seen that kind of status.

Comment: It's a mod, so we can't really tell without knowing what mod it actually is and where it's being used. It's definitely nothing from the base game.

Answer (score 3):

Usually in servers with mods like this, typing `/rank` in chat (press <kbd>T</kbd> to open chat) or in console (press the tilde <kbd>~</kbd> to open console) will display your current rank.

Comment: That's a backtick, not a tilde (~). Can you fix it with the correct character?

Comment: @pinckerman Aren't they the same key?

Comment: @Daedalus are they? I don't have a US keyboard, they are a different symbol to me

Comment: @pinckerman Ahh, well on US keyboards, or at least every keyboard I've used, they're the same key.

Comment: @pinckerman good catch, thank you.

Comment: @pinckerman I use a US layout so they are indeed the same key, but technically the default keybind to open the console for sourcemod games (such as CS 1.6) is (~), which can be separate keys. Edited my answer to reflect this.